# Question about separable extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Here is an assignment problem.$\\$

> Let $K/F$ be a finite field extension and $S=\{u\in K\ |\ \sigma(u)=u\ ,\forall \sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(K/F)\}$. Suppose $S=F$. Prove or disprove that $K/F$ is separable.$\\$

Because for a finite inseparable extension, the $F$ must be an infinite field of characteristic $p\neq 0$. So I've tried to find a counterexample like $F_3(t^{\frac{1}{6}})/F_3(t)$, where $t$ is not algebraic over $F_3$. However it doesn't work because $S$ is not $F$ but something between $K$ and $F$. $\\$

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps where OP writes $K=F$ (twice!) in the question, OP means "$K$ over $F$".

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean $K/F$.

Comment: Ok. Looks better. So $Emb(K/F)$ is the set of embeddings, and $K^{Emb(K/F)}$ is the set of common fixed points of all those embeddings?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F = \mathbb{F}_2(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are transcendental. Let $u$ be a root of $t^2 + t + x \in F[t]$, and let $K = F(u,\sqrt{uy})$ (where $\sqrt{uy}$ is the unique square root in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_2(x,y)}$).

The embeddings of $K$ in $\overline{F}$ which fix $F$ are given by $id$ and an embedding $\sigma$ which maps $u$ to its conjugate and $\sqrt{uy}$ to the corresponding square root; the set of fixed elements under these is exactly $F$.

But $K/F$ is not separable, since $\sqrt{uy}$ is inseparable over $F$.

Idea from Example 4.24 in Morandi, *Field and Galois Theory*.